# C++ Pass Boost::log severity level as argument to function

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I want to have only one function to write logs which would parse ellipsis and send result to the Boost::log, based on severity level. In header file would be defined different macros, which would select a correct severity level. There is the code:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

#define DEBUG(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(debug,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define INFO(msg, ...)          Logger::write_log(info,    msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define WARNING(msg, ...)       Logger::write_log(warning, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define ERROR(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(error,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);

namespace logging   = boost::log;

void write_log(auto level, const char *message, ...)
{
    char buffer[512];
    va_list args;

    // Parse ellipsis and add arguments to message
    va_start (args, message);
    vsnprintf (buffer, sizeof(buffer), message, args);
    va_end (args);

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(level) << buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DEBUG("Test string %s", "additional string");

    return 0;
}
```

But during compilation I get the next error:

```
 error: 'level' is not a member of 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial'
         BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(level) << buffer;
```

Seems that my level argument have an incorrect type. I also tried to use `logging::trivial::severity_level level` instead of `auto level`, but this didn't help. How can I fix this error?

UPDATED:

there is working solution:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

#define DEBUG(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(debug,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define INFO(msg, ...)          Logger::write_log(info,    msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define WARNING(msg, ...)       Logger::write_log(warning, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define ERROR(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(error,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);

namespace logging   = boost::log;

enum severity_level
{
    debug,
    info,
    warning,
    error,
    exception
};
src::severity_logger<severity_level> slg;

void write_log(severity_level level, const char *message, ...)
{
    char buffer[512];
    va_list args;

    // Parse ellipsis and add arguments to message
    va_start (args, message);
    vsnprintf (buffer, sizeof(buffer), message, args);
    va_end (args);

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, level) << buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DEBUG("Test string %s", "additional string");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL doesn't accept a variable, it needs one of the predefined level constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [boost log example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/log/trivial.hpp) and define:

```
// severity levels
enum severity_level
{
    trace,
    debug,
    info,
    warning,
    error,
    fatal
};
```

And you need to make your function to accept proper type:

```
void write_log(severity_level level, const char *message, ...){ ... }
```

Another option:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

#define DEBUG(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(logging::trivial::debug,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define INFO(msg, ...)          Logger::write_log(logging::trivial::info,    msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define WARNING(msg, ...)       Logger::write_log(logging::trivial::warning, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define ERROR(msg, ...)         Logger::write_log(logging::trivial::error,   msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);

namespace logging = boost::log;

#define LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)\
    BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS(::boost::log::trivial::logger::get(),\
        (::boost::log::keywords::severity = lvl))

void write_log(logging::trivial::severity_level level, const char *message, ...)
{
    char buffer[512];
    va_list args;

    // Parse ellipsis and add arguments to message
    va_start(args, message);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), message, args);
    va_end(args);

    LOG_TRIVIAL(level) << buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DEBUG("Test string %s", "additional string");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice: create your own severity. It's just an enum! Follow the source code of that "level" (using your IDE) to see that it's a simple enum. Copy it to your implementation, and change it as necessary. This is [how it looks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/log/trivial.hpp) (after changing its name):

```
enum my_severity_level
{
    trace,
    debug,
    info,
    warning,
    error,
    fatal
};
```

Take that to your code, and use it as necessary.

That `write_log` function should be like this:

```
void write_log(my_severity_level level, const char *message, ...) { ... }
```